# How to add a logo on the top left of MS Word document using the Python docx library?

Tags: python, image, docx

I am trying to add a small logo on the top left corner of my Word Document using the python-docx library. When I do try to add an image, using the code:

```
doc.add_picture('logo.png', width=Inches(1.2))
```

It seems to add it to the end of my word document. Can anyone help with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The Document .[add_picture](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart.html#adding-a-picture) method adds a specified picture to the end of the document in a paragraph of its own. However, by digging a little deeper into the API you can place text on either side of the picture in its paragraph, or both.

So you need `add_run` [doc](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart.html#applying-bold-and-italic)

So to add to the beginning of document you have to add first a `paragraph` to the doc and then add that pic to that `paragraph`

```
document = Document()
p = document.add_paragraph()
r = p.add_run()
r.add_picture('logo.png', width=Inches(1.2))
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. This also does the same thing and adds the logo to the end of the document. My goal is to add it right at the start of the document, basically in the header area

Comment: @m3214 have  you checked that https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/hdrftr.html

Comment: yes, thanks. I have a workaround and now just using a template doc with the logo existing. Thanks for your help.