# Make the header only appearing in the first page

Tags: python, docx, python-docx

I want to put an image on the top of the first page of the document so I pit on header now it's appearing on the rest of the pages would anyone propose another solution or how adapt it so it won't appear on the rest if the pages I am using docx on python

I tried `first_page_header` and `linked_to_previous` properties but no results

```
    doc = docx.Document()
    doc.sections[0].header.paragraphs[0].paragraph_format.left_indent = -Inches(1.25)
    doc.sections[0].header_distance = Pt(0)
    doc.sections[0].different_first_page_header_footer = True
    doc.sections[0].header.is_linked_to_previous = False
    doc.sections[0].header.paragraphs[0].add_run().add_picture("./image/french_header.png")
```

it removes header from the first page and make still on the rest of the pages I want the opposite

Comment: is this link helpful for you ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55709175/how-to-add-a-logo-on-the-top-left-of-ms-word-document-using-the-python-docx-libr

Answer (score 0):

i just used add_piture instead of working with header
here's the new version of my code

```
    doc = docx.Document()
    p = doc.add_paragraph()
    r = p.add_run()
    r.add_picture('./image/french_header.png')
    p.paragraph_format.left_indent = -Inches(1.25)
    # Set the top margin of the first paragraph to zero
    doc.sections[0].top_margin = docx.shared.Pt(0)
```